# Illustrator: Pattern Brush that narrows down all the way?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, brush

Has anyone knowledge on this Pattern Brush issue?

I want to make a line, which narrows down all the way from start to end. So I have made this form (see image) into a pattern brush. I have played with the pattern brush options as much as possible and have applied that pattern brush on a path I have made with the Pen tool, yet ending up invariably with a result something other than what was desired.

I'm using Illustrator CS5.

[image]

Comment: Might as well use a more legible font if you're going to post a question in picture form.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a "pattern" that goes all the way from the start to the end of a path you don't need a pattern brush you need an art brush. Just select "Art Brush" when creating your brush:

[image]

In this case though you'd be better off using a width profile. There is a default width profile exactly as your example:

[image]

You can also use the Width tool (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) to adjust the width manually of your stroke:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The width profile seems like a super easy way!

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is because the shape you have used for the brush is longer than the little diagonal lines you are drawing. So Illustrator is trying to cram them in between the corner anchors, but at the same scale.

One solution is to reduce the scale of the brush.

[image]

Perhaps this isn't what you want at all, I may have misread your quesiton. Another option is to create an Art brush.

[image]

Another option that might work is to choose the triangle profile for a regular stroke.

[image]

Comment: The effect you have achieved with the artbrush (lower left side) is definitely the one I've been after.

Comment: @kauneudenrakastaja I also added another method, using the stroke profile instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new on Stack Exchange.  … How do I paste an image from clipboard into a comment?

Comment: Oh snap, you edit your answer while I was writing mine!

Comment: @kauneudenrakastaja you can't paste images to comments, but you can use the uploader in the post editor (so edit your question or an answer) and copy the URL (just don't save the edit if you don't want the image in the post)

Comment: @Cai - yes.  I started answering the question, then realised I hadn't read the question properly, then deleted it and continued to edit. But to be fair, it's not really that clear what the desired ouput required by the OP is supposed to be.  Do you want me to delete mine. I'm not bothered one way or the other.

Comment: @Billy no, no need to delete!

Comment: @Cai okey dokey.

Comment: @kauneudenrakastaja you can also upload images to imgur and paste a link in your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **Scatter Brush**.

Leave the Rotation Relevive to: Page (this will not rotate the brush).

Play with the Spacing slider.

See the image below.

[image]